# Por que Netbeans 12.0 no me deja usar el var para declarar una variable?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-12

Estoy usando el JDK 14 y el JRE 8, dicen que el `var` se habilito como variable en Java y yo lo quiero usar ¿Cómo hago'.

Se supone que desde la versión 10 del JDK se puede usar pero yo lo habilito lo instale y aun así no me deja usar el var.

Fotos para la aclaración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/), publica el texto del código como tal, igual el texto de los mensajes de error que tengas.

Comment: puedes agregar una aptura de sources? Seguramente allí tienes mal el valor. Saludos.

Comment: puedes darle a a bombilla del error y decirnos que pone

Answer (score -2, accepted):

La solucion al problema fue usar IntellJ Idea como plataforma de desarrollo, ya que el netbeans 12.0 no me reconoce el JDK 14.

Comment: A la próxima, préstale atención a los comentarios y formula preguntas de acuerdo a las recomendaciones. De paso, marca tu respuesta como aceptada si finalmente esa es la solución

Comment: NetBeans 12 soporta hasta Java 16, esta no debería ser una solución válida.

Answer (score 1):

Estás accediendo a las propiedades de tu proyecto, en sí, debería funcionar por sí mismo, sin embargo, tu proyecto y Netbeans son dos cosas diferentes, puedes verificar la versión de la plataforma de Java que Netbeans está usando en "**Tools > Java Platforms**
,si la versión es anterior a la que deseas usar puedes agregarla haciendo click en **Add Platform > Java Standard Edition > C:\Program Files\Java**, selecciona la carpeta con un elemento extraño en el ícono del directorio y presiona **Next**, Netbeans detectará automáticamente la versión del JDK y finalmente podrás agregar la nueva plataforma, necesitarás reiniciar Netbeans después de eso.

Si eso no funciona, puede ser que hayas instalado recientemente una nueva versión sin haber reiniciado tu ordenador antes de probarlo en Netbeans.

Comment: No me sigue sin reconocer el var

Answer (score 0):

Dejo mi aportación aquí para los que puedan necesitarlo. Ese error sale porque, aunque tengas en tu sistema operativo versiones de JDK 10 o superior, que es necesario, es posible en en tu proyecto no esté marcado como tal. Para ello debes:

1. Propiedades del proyecto -> Botón derecho, darle click a *Properties*.
2. En *sources* verás abajo en *Source/Binary Format*, despliega el panel y selecciona cualquier versión desde la 10 en adelante, que es la versión que implementa la palabra reservada *var*.
3. Con ello, debería de haberse solucionado.

Saludos.

Comment: Me parece una buena respuesta

Answer (score 0):

- En mi caso yo descargue primero el JDK 13.0.2 y realice la instalación
- luego fui a Tools > Java Platforms > Add platforms (para seleccionar la otra versión del JDK)
- Después de realizar eso sobre mi proyecto di botón derecho, seleccione propiedades
  -En la parte de Source seleccione la versión 10 porque fue la que me funciono
  -En la parte de compile seleccione el JDK 13 que fue el otra JDK que yo instale.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]